# How to handle mouse dragging event in JFreeChart

Tags: java, mouseevent, jfreechart

I want to know whether it is possible to listen to the mouse event of dragging in JFreeCharts. By default it is assign to zooming. I remove this zooming functionality with,

`chartPanel.setDomainZoomable( false);

 chartPanel.setRangeZoomable( false);`

And I have used *ChartMouseListener* interface for listening to mouse events. I'm able to track click and move events.
But I'm unable to track the drag event.
So I want to know where, is there a way for tracking mouse drag event? Please help me on this.

Thnax in advance...

Comment: tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `mouseDragged()` in [ChartPanel](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html).